# Kotlin recyclerviewer not showing data

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-recyclerview

Our problem is displaying records from a `SQLite database` on an activity. We are able to write data to the database we verified that the data is written with `DBBrowser`. The other part of this issue is the `RecyclerAdapter`. We have spent two days construction the syntax. The program flow is simple one line of `EditText` is saved then we navigate to the `PersonActivity` that should display the saved data.
In the `PersonActivity` we query the database for all records and return a `contactList`. Our Design is `MVC`, We will post the code below for the `DBHelper` and the `RecyclerAdapter` and the `PersonActivity` to display the data with the `XML` files involved. Also the `Model Class`.

```
class Contact{
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""
}
```

`DBHelper` insert data and `queryAll DB` is created no need for all the code

```
// Start of CRUD functions
fun insert(values: ContentValues): Long {
    val Id = db!!.insert(dbTable, null, values)
    return Id
}

fun queryAll(): List<Contact> {
    val contactList = ArrayList<Contact>()
    val selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM $dbTable"
    val cursor = db!!.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)
    if (cursor != null) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                val contact = Contact()
                contact.id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(colId)))
                contact.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(colName))
                contactList.add(contact)
            } while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
    }
    cursor.close()
    return contactList
}
```

RecyclerAdapter **NOTE comments**

```
class PersonRecyclerAdapter(val context:Context, val 
    items:List<Contact>):RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 

    RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_card, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items.get(position)
        viewHolder.bindItem(item)

        //viewHolder.itemName.text = items[position]
        //  WHAT IS CORRECT SYNTAX FOR LINE OF CODE ABOVE
    }
    private fun Any.bindItem(item: Contact) {
        // AS Added this fun ?
    }
    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
       val itemName = view.tvName
    }
}
```

`PersonActivity` that should display the `contactList` data

```
class PersonActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var rvRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var contactList:List<Contact> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_person)

        val names = contactList

        rvRecyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvRecyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rvRecyclerView?.adapter = PersonRecyclerAdapter(this, names)

        callHOME()

    }

    private fun callHOME(){
        val db = DBHelper(this)
        contactList = db.queryAll()

    }
}
```

XML files for PersonActivity and the inflated file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.androidstackoverflow.kotlincontacts.PersonActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_person">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rvRecylerView">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Inflated view XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_new_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/color_Black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Please understand we have looked at numerous code variations for this problem!
Before we ask for help. The Questions are two fold 
How to show the data on the `PersonActivity`?
Is the `PersonRecyclerAdapter` syntax correct?

Answer (score 1):

First of all `callHOME()` should be called before initializing names variable. That is:

```
class PersonActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var rvRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
private var contactList:List<Contact> = ArrayList()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_person)

    callHOME()
    val names = contactList

    rvRecyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    rvRecyclerView?.setHasFixedSize(true)
    rvRecyclerView?.adapter = PersonRecyclerAdapter(this, names)
}

private fun callHOME(){
    val db = DBHelper(this)
    contactList = db.queryAll()

}
```

You also extended your PersonalRecyclerAdapter class with wrong `RecyclerView.Adapter<Recycler.ViewHolder>` you have to use `RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>`.
RecyclerView.Adapter with own ViewHolder as argument, not default view holder.

Using extension function here is overkill and unnecessary. Though could be used as follows..

```
class PersonRecyclerAdapter(val context:Context, val 
    items:List<Contact>):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
MyViewHolder {
     return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_card,parent, false)) 
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: MyViewHolder,    position: 
    Int) {
      val item = items.get(position)
      viewHolder.bindItem(item)
    }

    private fun MyViewHolder.bindItem(item: Contact) {
       itemName.text = item.name
       // or use
       // itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName).text = item.name
    }


}

class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val itemName = view.tvName
}
```

Instead just use this

```
 class PersonRecyclerAdapter(val context:Context, val 
    items:List<Contact>):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 
   MyViewHolder { return MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.single_card, parent, false)) }

   override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return items.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items.get(position)
        viewHolder.itemName.text = items[position].name
        // or use
        // viewHolder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvName).text = item.name
    }


}

class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

     val itemName = view.tvName
 }
```

Comment: I agree with the callHOME made the change. I can not tell you how frustrating extension functions are UGH but your code this line still is RED         viewHolder.itemName.text = items[position].name "itemName" ONLY

Comment: One more problem was there you extended your adapter with wrong ViewHolder as argument, you should extend it with your own ViewHolder not Recycler.ViewHolder. I updated my answer have a look, though I didn't ran it on IDE if problem continue please do ask.

Comment: I fought with that for hours and tried all types of syntax with your code when you do import Android Studio adds the RecyclerView PREFIX total pain so NO RED was the GOAL thanks for taking the time

Comment: You can use any other name for your viewHolder as well. That way Android Studio will not auto import, I updated my answer with changed name, i.e. "MyViewHolder". BTW welcome.

Comment: Also delegate your ViewHolder, i.e. make separate class for ViewHolder not the inner class of adapter.

Comment: If you are entering code for testing this I hate to ask but I can share the MainActivity and the DBHelper complete Still not seeing data in PersonActivity YES I appreciate the HELP

Comment: ERROR  E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Answer (score 0):

First off @kumarshivang made some very good suggestions about how to construct `RecyclerAdapter` and his best point was not to use the inner class. So I will post code here that uses a much cleaner code design for a `RecyclerAdapter`. Though even with a better constructed `RecyclerAdapter` our problem of not seeing the stored data was not solved. Because we knew that the data was in the database logic would tell us two things were wrong either the data had no container to show the view OR the data was not available YEP it was the latter and this one line of code in `PersonActivity` is what was missing.

```
listItems = db.queryAll()
```

Here is the cleaner `RecyclerAdapter` **(OFF to the Refactor FACTORY we GO)**
Notice the word "card" the author used a `CardView` widget to display data in the `RecyclerView` widget.

```
class HabitsAdapter(val habits:List<Habit>): RecyclerView.Adapter<HabitsAdapter.HabitViewHolder>() {

    class HabitViewHolder(val card:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(card)

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HabitViewHolder, index: Int) {

        if(holder != null){
            val habit = habits[index]
            holder.card.tvTitle.text = habit.title
            holder.card.tvDescription.text = habit.description
            holder.card.ivINsingle_card.setImageBitmap(habit.image)
        }
    }
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): HabitViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_card, parent,false)
        return HabitViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return habits.size
    }
}
```